# How to use Crypto++ or OpenSSL in XBox One (Durango)

Tags: windows, openssl, crypto++, xbox, xbox-one

I would like to use Crypto++ or OpenSSL in  XBox One (Durango). XBox One is not UWP. I download GitHub code but it does not support  XBox One compiler. I tried to compile Crypto++ or OpenSSL but they were not successful.

I would like to use md5 / dh / aes / rsa on XBox One.

How do I use Crypto++ or OpenSSL with XBox One?

Comment: *... download github code does not support xboxone (durango) compiler"* - For Crypto++ ... [Xbox Development Kit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xbox_Development_Kit) looks kind of old and does not mention Durango. I might be able to add Crypto++ support today if Microsoft provides the tools and makes an unencumbered download available and things "just work" like with desktops, servers and arm gadgets. We test ARM builds via an ARM Developer Prompt and [`cryptest.nmake`](https://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp/blob/master/cryptest.nmake). Is there an XBox Developer Prompt or similar?

Comment: Windows 10-based Core had replaced the Windows 8-based one in Xbox One The official developer kit was codenamed Durango,

Comment: Based on the download Crypto++ sln, I tried to create a new crypto ++ lib project for xbox-one, made some changes, the compiler was successful ... I will verify whether it can work tomorrow